Is mcsolve from QuTiP Optimal for Solving Large Systems in the Lindblad Master Equation?
I am transitioning from using Mathematica to Python for my work on quantum systems, specifically focusing on solving the Lindblad Master Equation. For this purpose, I've started using the mcsolve function from the QuTiP library.
I am aware that mcsolve performs Monte Carlo simulations to solve the master equation, which can be particularly useful for systems where exact analytical solutions are not feasible. However, I am concerned about the scalability and efficiency of this approach when dealing with large quantum systems.
My question is:
How does mcsolve perform for large quantum systems, say with thousands of dimensions? Is it computationally feasible, or are there limitations I should be aware of?
I appreciate any insights or recommendations you might have based on your experiences with large systems and the Lindblad Master Equation in Python.
Thank you.
